# Изменение текста на кнопке

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-xml

Есть кнопка Button. В ее background вставлен xml из drawable, которые изменяет фон этой кнопки при нажатии, фокусе, включенности, выключенности и тд и тп.

Вопрос: где и как мне прописать такое же для текста, который написан на этой же кнопке?

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, что вы конкретно хотите сделать с текстом

Comment: Добавить кнопку в активити, найти ее по id. Ну и потом button.setText........

Comment: @GinTasan изменить цвет. у кнопки, со стилем по умолчанию, цвет текста отличается от статуса кнопки вкл/выкл. вот это и надо сделать мне, но меня не устраивает стандартный черный цвет текста.

Comment: @Романыч я через xml хочу, а не топорно в активити.

Comment: @Wlad как раз таки через хмл это и есть вроде как топорно.  Ну или в атрибутах кнопки задайте текст да и все.

Comment: @Романыч в атрибутах кнопки можно вставить 2 цвета текста? 1 - когда кнопка включена. 2 - когда кнопка выключена.

Comment: Можно код скинуть ? Где обработка фона ?

Comment: @GinTasan обычный xml с <item android:state_enabled="true"> <item android:state_enabled="false"> <item android:state_pressed="true"/> и тд и тп. но это для фона кнопки. мне надо такое же, для текста внутри этой кнопки. оно где-то есть 100%, потому что кнопка с цветом по умолчанию так себя ведет. но стоит изменить color (цвет текста) в этой кнопке, цвет остается всегда стабильный.

Comment: @GinTasan отлично! помогло! черканите что-нибудь как ответ, чтобы я засчитал вам его!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Drawable прописать selector, а в layout файле сделать на него ссылку

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="..." />
    <item android:color="..." />
</selector>
```

Ссылка в layout файле:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector" />
```

Удачи в разработке !)